# When data is changed within the watch function, dom does not update

Tags: vue.js, v-model

Below is the data in a component

```js
data: function () {
      return {
        sltAreaStyle: {
          paddingTop: "3%",
        },
        checkedTypes: ["krw", "btc", "usdt"],
      };
    },
```

Below is watch function of checkedTypes data

```js
watch: {
      checkedTypes: {
        handler: function (newVal, oldVal) {
          if (newVal.length < 1) {
              alert("Choose one or more.");
              var last = oldVal[0];
              this.$data.checkedTypes = [last];
            
          }
        },
      },
    },
```

Below is my html template

```html
<div class="ckbxArea">
        <input type="checkbox" value="krw" v-model="checkedTypes">KRW</input>
        <input type="checkbox" value="btc" v-model="checkedTypes">BTC</input>
        <input type="checkbox" value="usdt" v-model="checkedTypes">USDT</input>
      </div>
```

I want to change the last value to `checkedTypes` data when all the check boxes are unchecked.
If the first checkbox was finally unchecked, the `checkedTypes` would be 'krw' like `checkedTypes = ['krw']` The `checkedTypes` data is `['krw']`, but all checkbox tags are unchecked. That is, dom has not been updated. I don't think I understand Vue's life cycle well. I think this problem is related to the life cycle of v-model and components, but I don't know what the problem is. Please explain why this problem occurs and tell me how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this is more about Vue rendering mechanisms for `v-model`eld input controls.

Check this:

1. Only one last checkbox is checked so model value is `['krw']`
2. Uncheck last checkbox
3. Watcher is executed - new model value is `[]` BUT the watcher immediately sets it to **same value as before** ... `['krw']`
4. Vue re renders the template (see the message in the console) BUT as the `v-model` value is same as during last render, it does not update the checkbox

Simple solution to situations like this is to postpone the update to next rendering cycle using [nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick)

```js
this.$nextTick(() => {
  this.checkedTypes = [last];
})
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function () {
    return {
      checkedTypes: ["krw", "btc", "usdt"],
    };
  },
  updated() {
    console.log("Component updated")
  },
  watch: {
    checkedTypes: {      
      handler: function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal.length < 1) {
          alert("Choose one or more.");
          //console.log("Choose one or more.");
          var last = oldVal[0];
          // this.checkedTypes = [last];
          
          this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.checkedTypes = [last];
          })
        }
      },
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.14/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" value="krw" v-model="checkedTypes"/> KRW
  <input type="checkbox" value="btc" v-model="checkedTypes"/> BTC
  <input type="checkbox" value="usdt" v-model="checkedTypes"/> USDT
  
  <pre>{{ checkedTypes }}</pre>
</div>
```